# How to create multiple volatile tables in Python from Teradata using pyodbc

Tags: python, teradata, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I am trying to run Teradata sql code in Python. The code involves building volatile tables but I still get error message when trying to create the second volatile table. Error Message below：

```
[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.  (-3932) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

My code is below:

```
sql1="""CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE A AS(......)WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(CUSTOMER_ID) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;"""
sql2="""CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE B AS(......)WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(CUSTOMER_ID) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;"""
cursor.execute(sql1)
cursor.execute(sql2)
```

Error shows when executing sql2 despite I tried making the two sql paragraphs into one and/or adding `BT;` and `ET;` I also tried switching `TMODE` in `pyodbc.connect` but it does not work as well.

Is there a way for python to handle multiple volatile tables like teradata did or is there another approach? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding an `autocommit=True` argument to your `pyodbc.connect` call.

Answer (score 0):

sql2 should be:

"""CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE B AS(......)
WITH DATA
PRIMARY INDEX(CUSTOMER_ID)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
END TRANSACTION;
"""